# I want to store the results of sm.OLS(y_train,x_train).fit().summary() to dataframe, so that i can use P>|t| value through code

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I want to use P>|t| value and compare with vif value and eliminate some columns automatically using code.
so I want to get P>|t| seperatly

```
x = df.drop(['price'],axis=1)
y = df['price']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=0.7,test_size=0.3, random_state=100)

#Applying stats model 
import statsmodels.api as sm
x_train = sm.add_constant(x_train)
lg1 = sm.OLS(y_train,x_train).fit()
data = lg1.summary()
data
```

so I want to get P>|t| seperatly. I have tried to save in csv like:

```
data.to_csv("data.csv")
data.to_html("data.html")
```

I also tried like:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get p-values from

```
results = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

which are presented in the output table under the column name "P>|t|" you can just use

```
pvalues = results.pvalues
```

or

```
pvalues = results.summary2().tables[1]['P>|t|']
```

and get pandas Series with required p-values